# jQuery - persist form data when changing back and forth between pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know there are several related posts on S/O about persisting data in webpage forms when navigating away from and back to pages, but thus far when trying to implement the suggestions, none of them help/pertain to my particular case.

Please see this codepen:

https://codepen.io/Nola111/pen/BaNJmrx

Note the Page 1 and Page 2 links in the top right of the screen.  If there is data in any of the fields on page 1, I need that data to persist if I switch to page 2, then switch back to page 1.  Same for if there is data in page 2 form, I need that to persist if you switch from page 2 to page 1 then back to page 2.

Apologies in advance if I did the multi-page approach on codepen incorrectly.  This is the only way I could see to do it.

Here is the code to comply with S/O rules:

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var endpoint = "http://localhost:53809/";

  /* eslint eqeqeq: 0 */

  $(".js-example-basic-single").select2();

  // Initialize modal
  $(".modal").modal();

  // Date Picker
  M.Datepicker.init($(".datepicker"), { format: "yyyy-mm-dd" });
  $(".modal").modal();

  const checkRads = () => {
    const checked = $("input[type=radio][name=group]:checked").val();
    const create = checked === "create";
    const update = checked === "update";
    const suppress = checked === "suppress";
    $("#proid").toggle(!create);
    $("#deleteid").toggle(suppress);
    $(".fields").toggle(!suppress);
    $("#btnSearch").toggle(update);
  };
  $(function() {
    $(".js-example-basic-single").select2();
    // Hide show inputs
    $("input[type=radio][name=group]").on("change", checkRads);
    checkRads();
  });

  $("form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(form)
      .find(":input")
      .prop("disabled", true);
    var selectedValue = $("input[name='group']:checked").val();
    switch (selectedValue) {
      case "create":
        newProfile($(this));
        break;
      case "suppress":
        deleteProfile($(this));
        break;
      default:
        updateProfile($(this));
    }
  });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body class="body-custom">
  <nav class="nav-custom">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right">
        <li><a href="https://codepen.io/Nola111/pen/BaNJmrx">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://codepen.io/Nola111/pen/qBdpVJq">Page 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="head">
      <div class="row">
        <h4 class="title">This is a website</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form">
      <div class="row">
        <form id="form" action="">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="type">
              <label>
                <input class="with-gap" name="group" value="create" type="radio" checked />
                <span>Create</span>
              </label>
              <label>
                <input class="with-gap" name="group" value="update" type="radio" />
                <span>Update</span>
              </label>
              <label>
                <input class="with-gap" name="group" value="suppress" type="radio" />
                <span>Suppress</span>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="proid" class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s11">
              <input id="profile_id" type="text" class="validate">
              <label for="profile_id">ID</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s1">
              <a id="btnSearch" class="btn-floating btn-small waves-effect waves-light teal lighten-2"><i
                  class="material-icons">search</i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Delete Reason -->
          <div id="deleteid" class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <select class="js-example-basic-single" name="deletereason" id="deletereason">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Choose delete reason</option>
                <option value="1">Reason 1</option>
                <option value="2">Reason 2</option>
                <option value="3">Reason 3</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row fields">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="validate">
              <label for="name">Name</label>
            </div>

            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <!--<select id="country">-->
              <select class="js-example-basic-single" name="country" id="country">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Country</option>
                <option value="Afghanistan;AFG">Afghanistan</option>
                <option value="Åland Islands;ALA">Åland Islands</option>
                <option value="Albania;ALB">Albania</option>
                <option value="Algeria;DZA">Algeria</option>
                <option value="American Samoa;ASM">American Samoa</option>

              </select>
            </div>
          </div>

        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Modal Structure -->
  <div id="errorModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4></h4>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you looked into local storage? Data persist is very easy that way. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic example of local storage:

https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/JjdMaKN

We have two inputs - the first I have pre-filled using value="", the second which is blank on page load. This is representing page 2 of a form.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
      <input id="user_inputted_data" type="text" class="validate" value="User inputted data">
      <label for="user_inputted_data">User Inputted Data</label>  
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s6">
      <input id="saved_data" type="text" class="validate">
      <label for="saved_data">Data from another page</label>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Then we saved some dummy data in local storage. This step would actually happen on page 1.

```
// This would happen on another page

var savedData = ['I am some saved data'];
localStorage.setItem('savedData',savedData)

// Here we check if there is anything saved. Try commenting the above lines out and saving thepen.

if (savedData) {

  $('#saved_data').val(savedData);

}
```

We check if there is anything save in local storage under that name, and if so, we fill out the input using that data. For the user inputted data, we check if the field has any value, and if so, we save it to local storage for use on page 3.

```
var userInputtedData = $('#user_inputted_data').val();

if (userInputtedData) {
    localStorage.setItem('userInputtedData',userInputtedData)
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks for this, you're a great help as always.  I will have a couple questions I think, as I try to follow this.  First, do I need to invoke `localStorage.setItem` on every field I want to persist, individually?

Comment: I'm asking because although my example is only two fields, the actual page form has 25 fields that need to persist.

Comment: Sean, as I read and re-read your answer, now I'm not sure if I was clear in what I'm asking for.  I'm not looking to, for example, have the value of the Profile Id field carry over from page 1 to the page 2 Profile Id field.  I'm not sure whether that's what your answer is doing, but I guess I'm confused by that `saved_data` element being in the HTML.  I just need for anything that's in the form on page 1 to still be there if I navigate away from page 1 and then navigate back to it.

Comment: You can save all the data from the form on page 1 in a single object, then retrieve it and loops though to put the data back in the form if the user goes back to page 1. My example is much simplified just to give you an idea. When the user goes to page 2, that is when you would do your first setItem - get all data, save as an object. Then when you come back to page 1, do a check to see if this user has data stored, and if so, populate form with it. Does that make sense? Let me know if I have misunderstood you.

Comment: Hi Sean, ok yes you definitely have understood me correctly, thanks for the clarification on that.  I'm taking another look at it now.

Comment: If you need to store an object, you may need to use JSON encode. Take a look at the mdn page, not required for arrays.